Ethers.js: getLogs returning empty results despite existing transactions
I'm working on a project where I need to track USDT transfers to specific wallet addresses and confirm them after a certain number of blocks. I'm using ethers.js to fetch logs for this purpose. However, I keep getting empty results from getLogs despite knowing there are relevant transactions. I checked Etherscan and there are transfers for that address.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
import { ethers, id } from 'ethers';
import { AppDataSource } from './config/data-source';
import { PaymentIntent } from './entity/PaymentIntent';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

const provider = new ethers.WebSocketProvider('wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/60df93ecf023472aaa84725af955fde2');

async function registerConfirmationChecker(walletAddress: string, paymentIntentId: number): Promise<void> {
    console.log(`Registering confirmation checker for wallet: ${walletAddress}`);

    provider.on('block', async (blockNumber) => {
        console.log(`New block received: ${blockNumber}`);
        const paymentIntentRepository: Repository<PaymentIntent> = AppDataSource.getRepository(PaymentIntent);

        const paymentIntent = await paymentIntentRepository.findOne({
            where: { address: walletAddress, status: 'paid' },
            relations: ['user']
        });

        if (paymentIntent) {
            console.log(`Processing payment intent: ${paymentIntent.id}`);
            const filter = {
                address: walletAddress,
                fromBlock: blockNumber - 20,
                toBlock: blockNumber,
                topics: [
                    id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)")
                ]
            };

            console.log(`Fetching logs with filter: ${JSON.stringify(filter)}`);
            try {
                const logs = await provider.getLogs(filter);
                console.log(`Filter result: ${JSON.stringify(logs)}`);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Error fetching logs:`, error);
            }
        } else {
            console.log(`No payment intent found for wallet address: ${walletAddress}`);
        }
    });
    console.log(`Confirmation checker registered for wallet: ${walletAddress}`);
}

LOGS:
Fetching logs with filter: {"address":"0x2d8fd1524d138c47b7999104087ce198e2a88f4b","fromBlock":20276500,"toBlock":20276520,"topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"]}
Filter result: []
No logs found for payment intent: 13
New block received: 20276604
Processing payment intent: 13
Fetching logs with filter: {"address":"0x2d8fd1524d138c47b7999104087ce198e2a88f4b","fromBlock":20276501,"toBlock":20276521,"topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"]}
Filter result: []
No logs found for payment intent: 13
New block received: 20276605
Processing payment intent: 13
Fetching logs with filter: {"address":"0x2d8fd1524d138c47b7999104087ce198e2a88f4b","fromBlock":20276502,"toBlock":20276522,"topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"]}
Filter result: []
No logs found for payment intent: 13


In your filter there is a walletAddress to retrieve the logs for. Instead the appropriate contract address should be added.
const filter = {
  address: walletAddress,
  fromBlock: blockNumber - 20,
  toBlock: blockNumber,
  topics: [
      id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)")
  ]
};

The address?: AddressLike | Array<AddressLike>; in the filter specifies what contract address / addresses should be the source of the emitted events.
To get events emitted by USDT you must include the USDT address in the filter instead of the walletAddress and then filter the retrieved events to find the proper one belonging to the walletAddress based on from or to topic
